# How to concatenate sum on apply function and print dataframe as a table format within a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to concatenate the 'count' value into the top row of my dataframe.

Here is an example of my starting data:

```
Name,IP,Application,Count
Tom,100.100.100,MsWord,5
Tom,100.100.100,Excel,10
Fred,200.200.200,Python,1
Fred,200.200.200,MsWord,5


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'IP', 'Application', 'Count'])
df_new = df.groupby(['Name', 'IP'])['Count'].apply(lambda x:x.astype(int).sum())
```

If I print df_new this produces the following output:

```
Name,IP,Application,Count
Tom,100.100.100,MsWord,15
................Excel,15
Fred,200.200.200,MsWord,6
................Python,6
```

As you can see, the count has correctly been calculated, for Tom it has added 5 to 10 and got an output of 15. However, this is displayed on every row of the group.

Is there any way to get the output as follows - so the count is only on the first line of the group:

```
Name,IP,Application,Count
Tom,100.100.100,MsWord,15
.................Excel
Fred,200.200.200,MsWord,6
.................Python
```

Is there anyway to write `dt_new` to a file in this nice format?
I would like the output to appear like a table and almost look like an excel sheet with merged cells.

I have tried `dt_new.to.csv('path')` but this removes the nice formatting I am seeing when I output `dt` to the console.

Comment: At bottom, when you say `dt` and `dt_new`, do you mean `df` and `df_new`, respectively?

Comment: CSV is a construct for storing text seperated by commas. Even if you design a spreadsheet in Excel and then save it as a CSV all of the formatting will be erased as csv does not support information about formatting. You can use to_html() in a jupyter notebook for pretty table formats. Otherwise you will need to find another technology

Comment: Also your output does not match your input. The result of `df.groupby(['name', 'ip', 'app'])['cnt'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).sum())` would be Tom, 100, MsWord, 10 in the first row. Perhaps you meant `df.groupby(['name', 'ip'])['cnt'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).sum())`

Comment: @WoodyPride Thanks for your reply, the .html sounds like a good suggestion. You are right about the df.groupby statement. I will update the post now

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of a challenge to treat a DataFrame and have it provide summary rows.  Generally, the DataFrame lends itself to results that are not dependent on position, such as the last item in a group. Can be done, but better to separate those concerns.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data = StringIO("""Name,IP,Application,Count
Tom,100.100.100,MsWord,5
Tom,100.100.100,Excel,10
Fred,200.200.200,Python,1
Fred,200.200.200,MsWord,5""")

#df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'IP', 'Application', 'Count'])
#df_new = df.groupby(['Name', 'IP', 'Application'])['Count'].apply(lambda x:x.astype(int).sum())

df = pd.read_csv(data)
new_df = df.groupby(['Name', 'IP']).sum()

# reset the two levels of columns resulting from the groupby()
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df.set_index(['Name', 'IP'], inplace=True)
new_df.set_index(['Name', 'IP'], inplace=True)
```

```
print(df)
                 Application  Count
Name IP                            
Tom  100.100.100      MsWord      5
     100.100.100       Excel     10
Fred 200.200.200      Python      1
     200.200.200      MsWord      5
```

```
print(new_df)
                  Count
Name IP                
Fred 200.200.200      6
Tom  100.100.100     15
```

```
print(new_df.join(df, lsuffix='_lsuffix', rsuffix='_rsuffix'))

                  Count_lsuffix Application  Count_rsuffix
Name IP                                                   
Fred 200.200.200              6      Python              1
     200.200.200              6      MsWord              5
Tom  100.100.100             15      MsWord              5
     100.100.100             15       Excel             10
```

From here, you can use the multiindex to access the sum of the groups.